# how to group the fields inside in some addselect in querybuilder?

Tags: json, symfony, orm, doctrine

what I want is simple, I want to group specific fields of a query with querybuilder in 3 different levels of relationship with an alias, to be clearer, I have 3 related tables, consulta (medical consultation), paciente(pacient), doctor (doctor), usuario (user), so with all what I get in my query is the medical consultation with its pacient data, plus doctor data and with its related user data, what I want is to omit irrelevant fields within those related tables, I'm using addSelect to include all the data among the levels of relationship but what I get is all the fields, I want to retrieve specific fields of the "paciente" table, and in the user table (which is the user related of the doctor), I will show how the scheme would be:

```
Consulta :{
        // omit the other fields
         {paciente: name and last name}
         {doctor: { usuario: name and last name}}}

$queryBuilder = $em->getRepository('MedicoBundle:Consulta')
               ->createQueryBuilder('e')
               ->leftJoin('e.paciente', 'a')
               ->addSelect('a')
               ->leftJoin('e.doctor', 'o')
               ->addSelect('o')
               ->leftJoin('o.usuario', 'u')
               ->addSelect('u')
               ->where('e.fecha =:fecha')
               ->orderBy('e.id', 'ASC')
               ->setParameter('fecha', $fecha)
               ->getQuery();
```

it retrieves all the fields which is not so bad, but I want to retrieve is some of them and omit others as I show in the scheme

Answer (score 0):

Just select what you want instead of selecting everything :

```
$queryBuilder = $em->getRepository('MedicoBundle:Consulta')
               ->createQueryBuilder('e')
               ->leftJoin('e.paciente', 'a')
               ->addSelect('a.name, a.lastname')
               ->leftJoin('e.doctor', 'o')
               ->addSelect('o.name, o.lastname')
               ->leftJoin('o.usuario', 'u')
               ->where('e.fecha =:fecha')
               ->orderBy('e.id', 'ASC')
               ->setParameter('fecha', $fecha)
               ->getQuery();
```

Though I do not know how you called your name and lastname attribute, so be careful with it.